# plugin save var inside each returned click

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml

You guys mind checking out this jsfiddle I made to help you understand my issue. http://jsfiddle.net/kr1zmo/DqbeX/8/:

```
<a href="#" class="cref">item</a>
<a href="#" class="cref">item 2</a>
<a href="#" class="cref">item 3</a>
<a href="#" class="cref">item 4</a>

<p id="result"></p>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
    $.fn.liveBindTest = function() {
        return this['live']('click', function() {
            var savedvar;

            if (!savedvar || savedvar == 0) {
                // is false, do false things.
                savedvar = 1;
                jQuery('#result').append(savedvar);
            } else {
                // is true, do true things.
                jQuery('#result').append(savedvar);
                savedvar = 0;
            }

            return false;
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.cref').liveBindTest();
});
</script>
```

I want to save a variable for each click.

Comment: You haven't set the `test` variable.

Comment: Why don't you write `this.live(...)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at **[this example](http://jsfiddle.net/DqbeX/5/)**.

Did you want to toggle which bit of code to execute? If you want to hold the value in a closure, you'll need to declare it outside of the live event handler function.

If the value needs to be held for each element matched by the selector, then you could use `$(elem).data()` to store the value like in this **[example](http://jsfiddle.net/DqbeX/9/)**.

Comment: the savedvar has to be independent for each one.

Comment: in that case, hold it in `$.cache` using `$(elem).data()`

Answer (score 2):

You declared your variable inside the event handler, creating a separate local variable for each handler.

You need to declare the variable outside the function.
If you want a separate variable for each element, you can declare the variable and add the handler in an `each` call, or use jQuery's `.data` function.

Comment: @kr1zmo: That's fine, although you should write `this.live(...)`.